# Why is this code blocking?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have some code which takes a short while to complete.   I'd like it to be handled on a separate thread as it is mostly blocked by IO.  To do this I implemented the following, but when the calling thread runs `background_picture_save()`, it seems to block.  Why?

I'm trying to get the `save_picture()` function to work as a background process.

```
static void * threaded_save_picture(void * p);
static void * threaded_save_picture(void * p) 
{
    char optarg[512];

    strncpy(optarg, p, sizeof optarg);  optarg[sizeof optarg - 1] = '\0';
    fprintf(stderr,"%s()::%s\n",__FUNCTION__,optarg);
    save_picture(optarg);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    return(p);
} /* threaded_save_picture() */

extern void background_picture_save(const char * const optarg);
void background_picture_save(const char * const optarg)
{
    pthread_t thrd;
    (void)pthread_create(& thrd, NULL, threaded_save_picture, (void *) optarg);
} /* background_picture_save() */
```

Comment: Why are you using ``pthread_detach``? If you never want to join the thread, just create it in the detached state.

Comment: What's the point of returning p if you're asking for "detach" ?

Comment: You should probably check for an error return from `pthread_create()`, although it is unlikely that would cause the program to block.  Another possible problem is that the string argument passed to the thread must have enough duration - be a static somewhere, or dynamically allocated - to allow for arbitrary scheduling of the threads.  If it is a local variable somewhere in the code that calls `background_picture_save()`, then it could be modified or released before the thread gets a chance to copy it.

Comment: @EmeryBerger: because I wasn't aware you could do that.

Comment: @ydroneaud: because of the function prototype; for no other reason than to avoid a warning.

Comment: @Jonathan: I agree with your asessment that `pthread_create()` is likely not failing, the lag in the calling code is consistent with the time it takes to run `save_picture()`.  The memory should be okay: it's allocated on the stack of the thread instance created by `pthread_create()` (which is why the instantiation is divided into the two functions and not specifying `save_picture()` directly.

Comment: The value that is safely on the thread stack is a pointer, not the array of characters at which it points.  I'm not convinced it is actually the source of your problem, but you do need to be excruciatingly careful about memory management for threads.  In fact, I'm not sure we can see the source of your problem; it is not self-evidently in the code you show, so it may well be in the code around the code you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the ambiguity out of your observations.

Run the program with gdb, when the main thread blocks print a backtrace with "where".

Use strace to show the system calls being made when blocking.

Use systemtap http://sourceware.org/systemtap/ to show kernel backtraces for the blocked process (although I see that pthreads support only recently went in http://www.cygwin.com/ml/libc-alpha/2011-01/threads.html#00010).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it in this order:

```
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
save_picture(optarg);
```

Comment: I suppose, but consider EmeryBerger's comments and the description of `pthread_detach` from the [opengroup website](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_detach.html): _The pthread_detach() function shall indicate to the implementation that storage for the thread thread can be reclaimed when that thread terminates._  No mention of causing the thread scheduler to run.

Comment: Be honest, I couldn't figure out why it blocked.  Perhaps you should try to replace the "save_picture(optarg);" line with something else (e.g. a sleeping loop) and see what happens.